# Google Places Search - Next Page Token returns same results

Tags: google-places-api

When I call

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=42.9825,-81.254&radius=50000&name=Medical%22Clinic&sensor=false&key=[KEY GOES HERE]
```

I get a set of results with next_page_token being available

now if i do the same

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=42.9825,-81.254&radius=50000&name=Medical%22Clinic&sensor=false&key=[KEY GOES HERE]&next_page_token=[NEXT PAGE TOKEN GOES HERE]
```

I get the same results as the first query not the next set of results

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The parameter should be `pagetoken`, not "next_page_token".

Try this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=42.9825,-81.254&radius=50000&name=Medical%22Clinic&sensor=false&key=[KEY GOES HERE]&pageToken=[NEXT PAGE TOKEN GOES HERE]
```

Comment: @Thomas Andersen can we get all results at once?

Comment: @Thomas Andersen sadly no

Comment: How do I get the actual token? I always get 20 results and don't see the token anywhere in the response. I've tried playing with the params, looking for things like bars in 5km range of a major city, so I definitely should get more than 20 results

Comment: @Ashish Saini Are you sure? Read Places API documentation: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests. The parameter is `pagetoken`.

Comment: how to set limit more than 20  ?

Comment: What possible values can be used on the `pagetoken` parameter? I cannot find any info about this. Should it be passed as an empty parameter (`&pagetoken`)?

Comment: `There is a delay of a few seconds between when a next_page_token is issued, and when it will become valid.`. Be sure to make some delay between next page requests.

Answer (score 1):

At first request you must use parameters without pagetoken while the following requests only pagetoken parameters, for example:

First request

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=42.9825,-81.254&radius=50000&name=Medical%22Clinic&sensor=false&key=[KEY GOES HERE]
```

Other request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?key=[KEY GOES HERE]&pagetoken=[NEXT PAGE TOKEN GOES HERE]
```

In case any parameters are entered in subsequent calls in addition to pagetoken and key, in the response the status will be set to INVALID_REQUEST

Comment: You are right .. the problem is the parameters passed in subsequent calls .. i changed the previous comment by adding more info

Comment: `INVALID_REQUEST` is only returned in this case: **There is a short delay between when a next_page_token is issued, and when it will become valid. Requesting the next page before it is available will return an INVALID_REQUEST response.** Also setting the `pageToken` parameter will cause other parameters to be ignored. It's safe to pass other parameters along with the page token parameter.

Refer to: [Accessing Additional Results](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging)

Comment: Please notice that parameter "pagetoken" is case sensitive, for me "pageToken" returned also INVALID_REQUEST